# How do you count two separate lines in a text file and assert that they are equal to one another?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Given a text file that includes a bunch of playstation 4 reviews I'm tasked with extracting out the lines that include "rating:" and "review:" by saving them to their own lists. I need to be able to use the

```
 assert len(ratings) == len(reviews)
```

command to find out if it was done right. The outcome should just be what the length is for both of them. I can count the lines of the entire text file but am completely and utterly lost at how to cut it up like asked. I am an utter amateur at programming itself. This is what I have so far.

```
ratings=[] 
reviews=[]
def line_count(fname):
    with open("PlayStation-4-Console_reviews.txt") as text_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(text_file):
            pass
    return i+1
print(line_count("PlayStation-4-Console_reviews.txt"))
```

The expected outcome is
38096

Comment: Could you add an example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in keyword to check if one string is a substring of the other:

```
if 'review' in line:
    reviews.append(line)
elif 'ratings' in line:
    ratings.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based Cory's answer you could do something like this:

```
ratings = []
reviews = []


def line_count(filename="PlayStation-4-Console_reviews.txt"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            if 'review' in line: reviews.append(line)
            elif 'rating' in line: reviews.append(line)


assert len(ratings) == len(reviews)
```

Comment: Just one issue - PEP 8 (Python's style guide) says you should never format if statements like that since it reduces readability.

Comment: I prefer writing if statements like this most of the time. I like reading my code this way rather than the extra indent. If someone else is reading the code, they can always auto-format it with pycharm (IDE I use).

Comment: Most of your coworkers will not enjoy it :)
I don't use an IDE so I would not be able to do that - And you shouldn't expect anyone you work with to use a specific IDE

Comment: true, currently I'm in high school and I've only worked by myself. I mean not specifically pycharm but an IDE that can autoformat

Comment: It's not a good thing to rely on - a lot of people in industry (including myself) use VIM.  It's a very powerful text editor, but it takes extra plugins to add things like autoformatting.  It's also not something that GitHub does, for example which is the place where a lot of code is read by others.

Comment: +1 on @CoryNezin's readability comments.  I'd also suggest just using the fact that iterating over a file yields lines, rather than reading it all in to memory before splitting it up.  i.e. `for line in f` is basically the same as what you're doing